# json deserialize field of internal object with jackson using data binding

Tags: json, parsing, jackson

I have a json like this

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "photo_urls":
    {
      "large": "http://www.server.com/john_photo.jpg"
    }
}
```

and I would like to deserialize it in one class, like this

```
public class Person
{
    String name;
    String photoUrl;
}
```

instead of this

```
public class Person
{
    String name;
    public class photo_urls
    {
        String large;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do it with Jackson using Data Binding and the annotation @JsonProperty? Or is it necessary to use the streaming API instead?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to have a setter method or a constructor parameter of the `Map<String,String>` type from which you can get the url field value. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonDeserialize {
    private static final String JSON = "{\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"john\",\n" +
            "    \"photo_urls\":\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "      \"large\": \"http://www.server.com/john_photo.jpg\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";


    public static class Person
    {
        private String name;
        private String photoUrl;

        @JsonCreator
        public Person(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("photo_urls") Map<String, String> photoUrl) {
            this.name = name;
            this.photoUrl = photoUrl.get("large");
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" +
                    "photoUrl='" + photoUrl + '\'' +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Person.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Person{photoUrl='http://www.server.com/john_photo.jpg', name='john'}
```